# Facebook get shared post id without publish_actions

Tags: javascript, facebook, ecmascript-6, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a form where the user is prompted to share the contest after they complete the form. From the [Facebook Documention](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) for the Share Dialog, it says that in the response data of the dialog will contain a `post_id` which is only available if the user has granted the `publish_actions`.

```
FB.login((response) => {

    // Make sure that the user really did login
    if(response.status === 'connected')
        this.fetchFacebook();

}, {
    'scope': 'publish_actions,public_profile,email,user_birthday'
});
```

However in the dialog, it says some permissions has not been approved yet by Facebook, which is the `publish_actions`.

Now my problem is, when I applied for a review, in the notes of the review it says that my app cannot use the Share Dialog...

> My app does not use the Facebook Feed Dialog or the Facebook Share Dialog to publish content.

```
FB.ui({
    'method': 'share',
    'href': url
}, (response) => {

    // My callback goes here
    console.log('Facebook share dialog response ::', response);

});
```

Everything works fine if I have the permission, but without it, the response from the Share Dialog of Facebook is empty, yet they don't want to approve the permission review.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to get the `post_id` of the published post without `publish_actions`?

Comment: _"I have a form where the user is prompted to share the contest after they complete the form"_ - you are not allowed to demand that, or incentivize it in any way. And if that is not the case, then your app should not need the post id in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe The user is prompted to share but is not forced to share it though.

Comment: Then what do you need the post id for? You are not allowed to promise them better chances in your contest if they share or anything like that either.

Comment: No it's just for stats purposes to see how many shares and likes for the client. Sharing does not grant them more chances to win in any form.

Comment: does't the response object have a `post_id` attribute? It does with the feed dialog

Comment: @madebydavid Yes it does, but it takes the `publish_actions` to have the `post_id` in the response object. Also, from the documentation, beginning October 12, 2016, `post_id` requires your app to have `publish_actions` granted, and for the user to share to their timeline or a group.

Comment: @ChinLeung did you find a solution or not yet? I have the same problem, I want to get the `post_id` without using the `publish_actions` permission

Comment: @ZiedCHAARI No I was not able to get the `post_id` without the permissions. However, I figured out an alternative to achieve what I needed without the use of the id.

Comment: @Chin Leung , I am also facing the same issue. Can u please let me know that what alternative solution you applied here?

Comment: @UdayrajKhuman I thought I needed the `post_id` to track the number of views but instead, I added the ID of my user in the permalink `?user_id=[id of the user]` and on load of the page I update the stats without using the `post_id`. Not sure if it would work for your case though.

Comment: @Chin Leung without publish_actions permission it is not allowed. I have approved publish_actions from my app and it is working fine now.